# Creating a custom form in active admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I need a simple form to add a range of phone numbers.

```
ActiveAdmin.register Did do
    # ..
    collection_action :add_range, :method => :get do
    end
    collection_action :add_range, :method => :post do
    end
end

<%= semantic_form_for [:admin, :dids, :add_range] do |f| %>
    <%= f.inputs :start, :end %>
    <%= f.buttons :commit %>
<% end %>
```

The above fails with "undefined method `model_name' for Symbol:Class".

How can I define a form like this that doesn't use an object directly?

Answer (score 2):

Just tried, this will work:

```
<%= semantic_form_for :range, :url => add_range_admin_dids_path do |f| %>
    <%= f.inputs :start, :end %>
    <%= f.buttons :commit %>
<% end %>
```

and then find the posted params in params[:range]

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar situation where I need to customize the form action attribute. So, the best way I found to achieve this was by creating a partial form in the corresponding view's folder.

First tell your resource you are going to use a custom form, so add this line to your resource file:

```
# app/admin/organizations.rb

form partial: "form"
```

Now you can create your partial by using [Arbre Components](https://activeadmin.info/12-arbre-components.html), like this example:

```
# app/views/admin/organizations/_form.html.arb

active_admin_form_for [:admin, resource] do |f|
  tabs do
    tab 'General Configuration' do
      f.inputs 'Organization Details' do
        admin_accounts = User.with_role(:admin).order('email ASC')
        site_collection = Site.where("subdomain <> ''").map { |site| ["#{site.subdomain}", site.id ]}
        f.input :name
        f.input :kind, :as => :enum
        f.input :carereceiver_kind, :as => :enum
        f.input :account_manager, :as => :select ,:collection => admin_accounts
        f.input :site_id, as: :select ,collection: site_collection
        f.input :office_phone
        f.input :office_fax
        f.input :office_address
        f.input :company_logo, :as => :file
        f.input :letterhead
        f.input :base_url, label: 'BASE URL'
        f.input :dynamics_url, label: 'DYNAMICS URL'
        f.input :genoa_site_id, label: 'GENOA SITE ID'
      end

      f.inputs 'Organization Settings' do
        f.input :demo_account
        f.input :appointment_not_started_notifications_enabled
        f.input :erx_enabled
        f.input :patients_can_book_appointments
        f.input :new_providers_can_manage_their_own_availability_by_default
        f.input :clarity_enabled
        f.input :whitelist_enabled
        f.input :bed_form_enabled
        f.input :patient_email_required, label: 'Require patient email addresses'
        f.input :patient_credit_card_required, label: 'Require patient credit card information'
        f.input :enable_patient_survey, label: 'Enable patient survey'
        f.input :enable_provider_survey, label: 'Enable provider survey'
        f.input :rcopia4_enabled, label: 'Rcopia 4 enabled'
        f.input :share_notes_across_providers_enabled
        f.input :d2c_mode
        f.input :sso_login_only
        f.input :allow_invited_patients_to_complete_profile
        f.input :allow_overlapping_appointments, as: :select
        f.input :media_mode, :as => :enum
      end

      f.inputs('Organization Contacts', { class: 'organization_contacts_section' }) do
        saved_contacts = f.object.organization_contacts.count
        n = 5 - saved_contacts.to_i
        n.times do
          f.object.organization_contacts.build
        end
        contact_counter = 0
        f.fields_for :organization_contacts do |m|
          contact_counter = contact_counter +  1
          m.inputs "Contact #{contact_counter}" do
            m.input :name, placeholder: 'Name'
            m.input :title, placeholder: 'Title'
            m.input :email, placeholder: 'Email'
            m.input :phone_number, placeholder: 'Phone Number'
          end
        end
      end
    end

    tab 'Appointment Parser Configuration' do
      f.inputs 'Appointment Parser Configuration' do
        f.input :appointment_parsers, as: :select, input_html: { multiple: true }
      end
    end

    tab 'EMR Settings' do
      f.inputs 'Settings' do
        f.input :emr_integrated, label: 'Enable EMR integration'
        f.input :emr_processor_type, as: :select, collection: Organization::AVAILABLE_EMR_PROCESSORS
        f.input :send_to_emr, label: 'Enable integration from 1DW to EMR'
        f.input :receive_from_emr, label: 'Enable integration from EMR to 1DW'
      end
    end

    tab 'Athena EMR Settings' do
      f.inputs 'Settings' do
        f.input :athena_practice_id, label: 'Athena Practice ID', input_html: { disabled: !f.object.has_athena_processor? }
        f.input :athena_department_number, label: 'Athena Department ID', input_html: { disabled: !f.object.has_athena_processor? }
      end
    end
  end

  f.actions
end
```

As you can see with `admin_organization_path` you can point the URL to any other you want but also you can customize the `method` to send the form.

> Also make sure you use `resource` for the `active_admin_form_for` block because you will get an error if you try to use something like `@organization`.
>
> The form contains a possible way to add **nested resources** to the principal one, every time you had configured the corresponding model relationships.

And with this, it should be working fine.
I hope it could be useful for someone else.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you need to have a model in your call to `semantic_form_for`. Since your action is a collection action it's not acting on a specific DID, so what model are you trying to create? A Range model? If that is the case you should just have something like:

```
<%= semantic_form_for [:admin, @range] do |f| %>
  <% ... %>
  <%= f.buttons :commit
<% end %>
```

Of course `@range` should be initialized as `Range.new` in the controller.

Edit: Realized a bit late that you don't want to use an object. In the [documentation](http://rdoc.info/github/justinfrench/formtastic/Formtastic/Helpers/FormHelper#semantic_form_for-instance_method) it indicates that you can use `semantic_form_for :login`, but it might not work with nested / namespaced forms. You'd probably have to specify the `url` with `:url => admin_add_range_dids_path` or something similar. Just check `rake routes` to find the right naming. Not sure if the model is being called by ActiveAdmin or Formtastic, so that still might not work, but it's worth trying.